# Traditional IRA - First Home Purchase - Does the $10K limit apply to each spouse or the entire household?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, ira

One can withdraw up to $10K for first time home buyer. My question is if each spouse can make the withdraw or is 10K by purchase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make sure your spouse qualifies as a first-time homebuyer as well, if
>   you are married and buying the property together. Each of you may take
>   $10,000 from your traditional IRAs.

Source: Link in your question - http://www.wikihow.com/Buy-a-Home-With-IRA-Money

Comment: No worries. :)  Glad to help.